# How to bind rows in R based on string?

Tags: r, data-binding, rbind

I want to tidy my data by summing the data in each column by the CCG name. 
I essentially have 12 months worth of data separated for each CCG in this data frame but I want to sum it to just get one row with all the information.

[here is a pic of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN07l.png)

For example I have 12 entries in my data frame for NHS Darlington CCG and want to sum all the columns (ReferralsReceived, FirstTreatment, etc) to just have one result for NHS Darlington CCG and not 12.

But I want do this for every CCG in the column CCGName.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide your dataset in a copy paste friendly format (you can use `dput`), instead of posting a screenshot. Also, let us know what you have already tried. Check out this post to know how to create a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/aggregate.html), if I understand correctly:

```r
df <- data.frame(
    name = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
    number = c(2,2,4,4)
)

#   name number
# 1    a      2
# 2    a      2
# 3    b      4
# 4    b      4

aggregate(df$number, by = list(name = df$name), FUN = sum)

#   name x
# 1    a 4
# 2    b 8
```